# xslt condition for multiple line of text column

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, dataviewwebpart

i am having one issue in displaying description column data from the list in data view web part.Actually in my list i've a column named as Description type of this column is multiple line of text what i want if length of the text in description column is greater than 20 characters than display only 20 characters otherwise show all characters. I've written the following xslt to do that.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(@Description) &gt; 20">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(@Description, 1, 20)" />...


      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:value-of select="@Description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>       

      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Same thing is working for the column whose type is single line of text,can anyone tell me how to achieve this for the column whose type is multiple line of text

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean you want the first 20 characters **of each line**? How are the lines separated (show an example of the XML source)?

Comment: Actually in my list I've a column named as Description type of this column is multiple line of text what i want is if length of the text of any item in description column is greater than 20 characters than display only 20 characters otherwise show all characters.the xslt i used is mentioned above.am i clear now

Comment: Why do you treat the two cases differently as far as the output escaping is concerned?

Comment: i tried to use output escaping for the first case as well but it displays only this output.

<div ...

it does'nt render text only shows the div and few dots.

Comment: "*in my list I've a column named as Description*" You have tagged your question as XSLT so presumably your input is XML. There are no "lists" or "columns" in XML. Perhaps that's something that exists in SharePoint - but XSLT works with XML.

Comment: actually i am working in  sharepoint's data view webpart in which we use xslt,so i need help for that.

Comment: can anyone suggest me resoultion for the above mentioned requirement.

Comment: There is nothing to worry about multiple lines. Your code looks OK to me. I think you are counting character by own and expecting same result by string-length(). But, if you have multiple enter or space in your text() and you are not using normalize-space() then your output would be differ. Put normalization around @Description like normalize-space(@Description) and confirm.

Comment: actually what i want to do is:
if any list item has more than 20 characters than show only first 20 characters otherwise show all characters that's what i tried to accomplish through the above code.

please suggest resolution for that issue